# Sublime text bracket highlighting

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I have downloaded sublime text 2 and sublime text 3 but cannot find how to enable bracket highlighting - am using windows - have searched the internet but those solutions are not applicable. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aptly named [BracketHighlighter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BracketHighlighter) plugin is very good not only for highlighting but also for other bracket-related operations.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the BracketHighlighter plugin is to make a modification to your color scheme. You could add the following code to the `settings` section of your color scheme file:

```
<key>bracketsForeground</key>
<string>#00FFFF</string>
<key>bracketsOptions</key>
<string>foreground</string>
<key>bracketContentsForeground</key>
<string>#00FFFF</string>
<key>bracketContentsOptions</key>
<string>foreground</string>
```

And then you would get the following result:

[image]

Obviously you could change `#00FFFF` to whatever color you want.